# .after() in angularjs (nested ng-repeat recursive iteration)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple structure

```
 function linksRarrange($scope) {
    $scope.links = [
        {
            text: 'Menu Item 1',
            url: '#',
        },{
            text: 'Menu Item 2',
            url: '#',
            submenu: [
                {
                    text: 'Sub-menu Item 3',
                    url: '#',
                },{
                    text: 'Sub-menu Item 4',
                    url: '#',
                    submenu: [
                        {
                            text: 'Sub-sub-menu Item 5',
                            url: '#',
                        },{
                            text: 'Sub-sub-menu Item 6',
                            url: '#',
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },{
            text: 'Menu Item 3',
            url: '#',
        }
    ];
}
```

I wish to build a table where the children are rendered in a row the children after the parent eg:

Menu Item 1

Menu Item 2

Sub-menu Item 3

Sub-menu Item 4

Sub-menu Item 5

Sub-menu Item 6

Menu Item 3

```
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
     <th>Title</th>
     <th>Url</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
     <td>Menu Item 1</td>
     <td>#</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Menu Item 2</td>
     <td>#</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Sub-menu Item 3</td>
     <td>#</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Sub-menu Item 4</td>
     <td>#</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Sub-menu Item 5</td>
     <td>#</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Sub-menu Item 6</td>
     <td>#</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Menu Item 3</td>
     <td>#</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I have looked at using ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end, but this doesn't support what I want to do.

Can anyone offer any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current solution is not perfect, in fact the resulting html is not a table/tr but a set of nest ul/li elements that are then styled using css to emulate the design spec.

The causal factor is due to the problems with the placement of tbody an tr within a directive. If anyone has a workaround I would be very grateful for you to share this please.

The simple markup is as follows:

```
<menucollection menucollection='links'></menucollection>
```

Supported by 2 directives:

```
window.app.directive('menucollection', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            menucollection: '='
        },
        template: "<ul><menuitem ng-repeat='menuitem in menucollection' menuitem='menuitem'></menu></ul>"
    }
});

window.app.directive('menuitem', function ($compile{
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            menuitem: '='
        },
        template: "<li>{{menuitem.Name}}</li>",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.catMarker = attrs.marker;
            scope.subcatMarker = attrs.marker + ' »  ';

            if (scope.menu.Children.length > 0) {
                element.append('<menucollection menucollection="menu.submenu"></menucollection>');
                $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using this for navigation you can put it in a nested `<ul>` and us nice css to style it.  something like:

```
<ul ng-repeat="menu in links">
  <li>{{menu.text}}</li>
  <ul ng-repeat="subs in menu.submenu">
    <li>{{subs.text}}</li>
  </ul>
<ul>
```

... something like that

Comment: while this solution works, I don't think it solves the recursive issue the OP is asking about; it doesn't handle cases where there is a menu > sub > subsbub

Comment: using nested ul is not unacceptable in html, this is actually my plan b if I cannot find a more elegant solution ;)

Comment: Thanks.  The links below are helpful if you want a more dynamic solution.  But if you know the size and shape of the JSON you can nest `<ul>`s all day long.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at these resources:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/TbpjE-5XEM0/yUi8wqc7sWoJ

http://sporto.github.io/blog/2013/06/24/nested-recursive-directives-in-angular/

I think the first example in the first link can be fitted to match your need.

This is definatly not the first time this question has been asked and I think you can find a lot more of these examples if not a direct hit at what you're looking for if you just google it up.